# How to disable AWS parameter store autoconfiguration for tests?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws

I have added `spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config` dependency as explained in the [spring documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.0.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html#_integrating_your_spring_cloud_application_with_the_aws_parameter_store). Now, for unit tests I want to disable parameter store configuration. But not able to do it.

I tried setting following property in test/application.properties

```
 aws.paramstore.enabled=false
```

Also tried excluding `AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.class` from `AutoConfiguration` but still not working.

Exception

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
>   Failed to instantiate
>   [com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagement]:
>   Factory method 'ssmClient' threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a region via the
>   region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region in the builder
>   or setup environment to supply a region.  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:582)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]   ... 83 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to find a
>   region via the region provider chain. Must provide an explicit region
>   in the builder or setup environment to supply a region.   at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.setRegion(AwsClientBuilder.java:371)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.336.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder.configureMutableProperties(AwsClientBuilder.java:337)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.336.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.336.jar:na]  at
>   com.amazonaws.services.simplesystemsmanagement.AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.defaultClient(AWSSimpleSystemsManagementClientBuilder.java:44)
>   ~[aws-java-sdk-ssm-1.11.336.jar:na]   at
>   org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.paramstore.AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.ssmClient(AwsParamStoreBootstrapConfiguration.java:53)
>   ~[spring-cloud-starter-aws-parameter-store-config-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to disable paramstore with alternative approach by adding the property (`aws.paramstore.enabled=false`) to `bootstrap.properties` file test resources folder. This one is much simpler solution

**Older solution**

I was able to figure out the solution. Seems that `SpringBootTest` tries to load `ssmClient` even before the test configuration class, and before loading `application.properties`. The solution is to disable paramstore by specifying the property on `@SpringBootTest` itself

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class, properties = {"aws.paramstore.enabled=false"})
```

Comment: @sidgate : If we add the property in bootstrap, and make it disabled then we need to enable it for all other env that require this property in the classpath.

Comment: need to add only in `src/test/resources/bootstrap.properties`